# texdoc not working

Tags: texdoc

Although I have MacTeX installed, running `texdoc -l amsmath` did not return the documentation (I'm pretty sure amsmath is installed as confirmed by tlmgr). Nothing returned when I ran `man texdoc`. Is there some fix to this, or how can I reinstall texdoc? Thanks!

Comment: Does `texdoc amsmath` or `texdoc beamer` work (without the list option `-l`)?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner No, here's the error message `Sorry, no documentation found for "amsmath".
If you are unsure about the name, try full-text searching on CTAN.
Search form: <https://www.ctan.org/search/>`

Comment: My point was if other package names work :). First we want to make sure that the command works in principle. I am not a Mac user so I cannot help a lot :(

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: It seems like texdoc is working in principle but the file is not on your system OR texdoc looks in the wrong places for the file.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I ran `which texdoc` and got `/Library/TeX/texbin/texdoc` Don't know which directory it's looking at, also not sure where the package documentations are stored